# Spring Bean Service class instance variable and threading issue in a web application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-bean

I have a `Spring 5` based webapp where the `controller` calls this `service` class and gets the current logged in `User` information.

Since `loggedInUser` object has been defined as an instance variable here, will this create a race condition when multiple users try to log into the application and access pages with their credentials ?
Should this be a local variable instead of instance variable within the `getLoggedInUser()` method ?

I was under the impression that `Tomcat` will create a new thread for every `HTTP` request and a brand `new` instance of `UserService` bean will be created every time a request comes in, irrespective of the user accessing it.

And how can I identify if the bean used by `Spring` is `new` instance or `singleton`? Is there a way to check this at runtime using `System.out.println()` or any other methodology/tool?

So,

```
User 1 -> new UserController()    -> new UserService() -> welcome.jsp 
User 1 -> new ProductController() -> new ProductService() -> new UserService() -> product.jsp  

User 2 -> new UserController()    -> new UserService() -> welcome.jsp 
User 2 -> new ProductController() -> new ProductService() -> new UserService() -> product.jsp
```

**UserService.java**

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    private User loggedInUser;

    public User getLoggedInUser(HttpServletRequest request) {
        if (this.loggedInUser != null) {
            return this.loggedInUser;
        }
        this.loggedInUser = (User) session.getAttribute("loggedInUser");
        return loggedInUser;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default scope for Spring beans is `singleton` [Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.3.0-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-scopes). This means that only one instance of a bean will be created. This can be demonstrated by the following snippet of code.

```
@RestController
public class TestController {
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public void test() {
        System.out.println(this);
    }
}
```

Every time `/test` endpoint is called, the output will be the same, something like this:

```
com.example.TestController@17870d99
com.example.TestController@17870d99
com.example.TestController@17870d99
```

Using a different scope, (`request` scope, for example), running the following code:

```
@RestController
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION)
public class TestController {
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public void test() {
        System.out.println(this);
    }
}
```

we will get the following output:

```
com.example.TestController@3213427f
com.example.TestController@2318434f
com.example.TestController@5e0df012
```

We can see that the controller is instantiated with every session (in our case with every call to `/test` end-point).

Now, it is not recommended to use an instance variable in a singleton bean, since this will have unintended consequences (like race conditions, or leaking unauthorized data). If we would want to use an instance variable, we should use the appropriate scope for the bean.

Or just avoid instance variables at all.

Answer (score 2):

Spring IoC container will create `UserService` once and will inject the dependency where it is used if this is `Singleton` which is the default.

You can use [VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/) to take a heap dump and analyze.

And changing `loggedInUser` to be a [`ThreadLocal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) might help.